# What type of pin is this?

Tags: hardware

Does anyone know what type of pin this is? Pictures shows pin alone and pin in use for attaching a bucket to a loader adapter. It has a hole for a cotter pin.
[image: Pin alone]

[image: Pin holding bucket on.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the part in the [parts manual for an allied 595](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/4468/Buhler-Allied-595.html?page=27#manual) loader. Its a pin weldment or a Allied Bucket Quick Attach Pin.

Answer (score 4):

It is a hitch pin with a homemade handle.  At least I think the handle is homemade.

They are used to attach trailers/wagons, machinery to farm tractors.  They are also used to connect loaders/buckets to the tractors.

Comment: Considering this might get dragged through mud, it looks carefully designed so the cotter pin is in a well protected location, compared to a regular hitch pin. But this specific pin does look like a homemade replacement for the original.

Comment: Thanks @crip659 the top picture does look like a homemade one, however since the bottom picture shows the handle being used to keep the pin in position I figured it was a type of pin that had a name other than just a hitch pin. I ask because I need to buy another one.

Comment: @Kyle  If you have a local tractor supply or dealer they might have a specific name, maybe a locking hitch pin.